# How can I setup a VPN connection inside nodewebkit (NW)

Tags: javascript, vpn, node-webkit, nw.js

Is there any way of getting VPN connection inside NW app?
I want only requests from NW app to go through VPN, not system-wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there won't be any platform independent solution and you do not specify a platform.

Node.js API contains function `child_process.execSync` (look into [nodejs doc](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options)) that allows you to call any system command. And for example on Windows you can establish VPN with `rasphone` command ([more here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/125393)), e.g.:

```
rasphone -d my_vpn_name
```